# Recipe for tracking in Python coroutines the chain of current awaits in a neat way

Tags: python

Want to know on which awaitable a Python `asyncio` task is currently on?

After some research, I did not found anything from the Python 3 asyncio library on how to know the current `await` or `yield from` directive a `Task` instance is currently on.

I want to share this with you: feel free to give some advice on how it can be improved or if something better exists from your own recipes or from the standard library itself :)

```
import inspect
import linecache
import traceback

def get_awaitable_stack_trace(task, file):
    """
    Get the callstack representing the chain of awaits-yield from directives
    that a Task object is currently on.

    :param task: The Task object.
    :param file: The file-like object on which the callstack is written.
    """
    extracted_list = []
    coro = task._coro
    while True:
        # Get the information on the current coroutine or generator.
        coro_name = coro.__name__
        try:
            frame = coro.cr_frame
        except AttributeError:
            frame = coro.gi_frame
        coro_filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
        await_line_number = frame.f_lineno

        linecache.checkcache(coro_filename)
        line = linecache.getline(coro_filename, await_line_number,
                                 frame.f_globals)

        # Record the stack trace info for this coroutine.
        extracted_list.append(
            (coro_filename, await_line_number, coro_name, line))

        # Get the next awaitable object in the chain.
        try:
            coro = coro.cr_await
        except AttributeError:
            coro = coro.gi_yieldfrom
        if not inspect.isawaitable(coro):
            break

    traceback.print_list(extracted_list, file=file)
```

Given this code:

```
async def coro_1():
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(999)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # Do something.
        pass

async def coro_2():
    await coro_1()
```

A task that calls `coro_2`, when passed to `get_awaitable_stack_trace`, will produce this call stack:

```
File "D:\Dev\Git\test.py", line 164, in agent
  await coro_2()
File "D:\Dev\Git\test.py", line 148, in coro_2
  await coro_1()
File "D:\Dev\Git\test.py", line 142, in coro_1
  await asyncio.sleep(999)
File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 508, in sleep
  return (yield from future)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, what a pleasure to see this. You are legendary.